# How to custom sort the return values of Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, sorting, directory, getfiles, system.io.file

I am loading a list of files placed in a directory in a string array. I am using `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()`,

```
String[] path = Directory.GetFiles(batchElements[j].DocIdPath, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I'm assuming the default sort order of the returned values is by name. So my files are loaded in the following order.

- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_1.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_10.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_11.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_2.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_3.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_4.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_5.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_6.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_7.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_8.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_9.csv

But instead i want to collect the values in this order.

- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_1.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_2.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_3.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_4.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_5.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_6.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_7.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_8.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_9.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_10.csv
- 2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_11.csv

Appreciate help.

Comment: Then I suggest you implement a comparison which is able to spot that. Note that you should be able to code it and test it without any reference to `Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: You probably want to read http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/ too

Comment: Will the first part of the files always be exactly "2713_CFPB Settlement Cost Booklet_2713_"?  Or can we count that the number part will always be the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

- Get File name only using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`
- Split them based on `_`
- Get Last item
- Parse it using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`
- Use that value in `OrderBy` with LINQ

Code:

```
var output = path.OrderBy(p => 
                        int.TryParse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p).Split('_').Last(), out temp) ?
                        temp : int.MaxValue);
```

If you need an array or `List<T>` as output then append `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to the query.